# How can I check for DBNull while executing my command only once?

Tags: .net, sql, database, ado.net

When I retrieve any Scalar value from the database, I usually write code like this for nullable fields.

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

But I don't like it because it executes the Executescalar statement twice. It's an extra trip to the server for my website and in favor of performance I don't want to do this.

Is there any way I can get rid of this extra ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: The obvious choice is to use two lines. Is there a reason you wrote it this way? If it is just to keep it to one line I think that is taking terseness to an extreme degree.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write yourself an extension method for the sql command.

```
public static T ExecuteNullableScalar<T>(this SqlCommand cmd)
    where T : struct
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result == DBNull.Value) return default(T);
    return (T)result;
}
```

Usage becomes:

```
int value = cmd.ExecuteNullableScalar<int>();
```

Comment: setting up T : struct does not allow one to use strings. I removed the inheritance.

Comment: For anyone who is trying to use this solution for vb one of the important changes is `result == DBNull.Value` changes to `result is DBNull.Value`. If you try and use the `=` operator, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 12):

Just use a variable to cache the result:

```
var o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return o == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)o;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 return (o== DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (int)o;
```

Comment: I prefer this over "var." I think the use of "var" is, as I expected, being abused. Although, I do realize that some people, Jon Skeet for example, believe it is more readable, which I don't understand.

Comment: Really? You care what type "o" is in that code? It's getting discarded on the very next line. As a reader of the code, the use of "object" vs "var" is just noise to me.